# How can I set the center of scaling?

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, scale, centering

I'm working in some graphics programming in java. At the moment I can scale a picture image what I store in a 1D array. (it store row by row)

My code like where is the new position?
`newpoz = (int)(x * scale) + (int)(y * scale) * width;`

This gives me a position in the array. But it scaling by the 0,0 coordinate what is in the top left corner. How can I set it to the center if the screen? So to the screen.getWidth()/2;screen.getHeight()/2.

[Demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKySU.png)

Somebody can help with this? If there is any question I will answer in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scale pixel coordinates about some center `(a, b)`:

`(x', y') = ([x - a] * scale + a, [y - b] * scale + b)`

Fetch the original pixel data using `pixelArray[y * width + x]` as before, and set the destination pixel similarly with the new coordinates.

EDIT: you may also want to look at *bilinear interpolation*, because the current raw method may give jagged edges in the final image if used directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you first translate the Center of the image to (0,0), then scale the image, then translate the image back, you will have effectively scaled the image with your desired centering.

- x1 = x - screen_width/2
- x2 = x1 * scale
- x3 = x2 + screen_width/2

Ditto for y axis.

With a bit of math, you can do this all in one step.  Exercise left to student.

But if you get in trouble, post your attempt, and then we can help you fix the code.